# Printing an element which is not a regular string with python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am struggling to print an element on a website. It has text in it but is not actually a string, making it hard for me to print that string if it is even possible. The element is on the apple music website, specifically it is the genre and release year of an album. Here is a link to the first album that came to mind: https://music.apple.com/us/album/the-essential-teddy-pendergrass/1550372297

I am using python selenium and webdriver for this entire project. I have tried this line, which I have used to print string elements, but here it does not work:

```
genre = wait.until(visible((By.CLASS_NAME , 'product-meta typography-callout-emphasized'))).text
```

Here is the error:

```
genre = wait.until(visible((By.CLASS_NAME , 'product-meta typography-callout-emphasized'))).text
  File "D:\Python App\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

The element is under the artists name, so, for example, here, I would like to print "R&B/Soul 2007". How could I do that?

Comment: as I remeber Selenium may have problem with multi classes - it treats it as a single class  and it doesn't add dot between classes - and you have to add it manually 'product-meta.typography-callout-emphasized'. This problem doesn't exist when you use `xpath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.get("https://music.apple.com/us/album/the-essential-teddy-pendergrass/1550372297")

genre = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-meta typography-callout-emphasized']")
print(genre.text)
```

Prints:

```
R&B/SOUL · 2007
```

You may want to add a `wait` around that element though just in case.  I just did the quick version